# How To Call Child user Control Events on Parent Pages

Tags: asp.net

I have two User Controls. And one aspx page which is loading the controls. Code is given Below

Home.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="MYApp.Home" %>


<asp:Panel ID="pnlTabs" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Home.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

base.LoadUserControl(UC_Tabs, pnlTabs);

}
```

Tabs.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UC_Tabs.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.UserControls.UC_Tabs" %>                        <asp:Button ID="btnPhotoTab" runat="server" Text="Photos" CssClass="tab_style" style="border-right:none;"  onclick="btnPhotoTab_Click" />



<asp:Panel ID="pnlPhotos" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Tabs.ascx.cs:

```
 protected void btnActivityFeed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Home HomePage = (Home)this.Page;
             LoadUserControl("UC_PhotoSearch.ascx", pnlPhotos);
         }


        public Control LoadUserControl(string ControlName, Control Container)
         {
             Control UControl = null;
                            if (ControlName != null)
                 {
                     UControl = this.LoadControl("~/UserControls/" + ControlName);
                     UControl.ID = UControl.GetType().Name;
                     Container.Controls.Add(UControl);
                 }
                                   return UControl;
         }
```

UC_PhotoSearch.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UC_PhotoSearch.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.UserControls.UC_PhotoSearch" %>
 <input id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" type="text" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
 <span id="PhotoSearchedData" runat="server"></span>
```

UC_PhotoSearch.ascx.cs:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             //Photo Search Code here
         }
```

The above is all my code. 
Now I am loading the Tabs control on Home page and

Photo search Control on Tabs control

Now I click on Search Button But the

btnSearch_Click in not firing and even the page load event is also not firing.

How can I able to Access the  btnSearch_Click event from home page.

If I used the following on Tabs control then the button click is working fine.

```
<%@ Register Src=”UC_PhotoSearch.ascx” TagName=”PhotoSearch” TagPrefix=”uc1″ %>
 <uc1:PhotoSearch ID=”PhotoSearch″ runat=”server” />
```

So what is wrong with dynamic loading of controls.

Please Help me

Comment: are you sure the IDs are unique?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you quite, but I think if you load your controls in the Page's PreInit event and not Page_load your events will fire.